# cfapi: CfDehydratePlaceholder seems to be stucked

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, minifilter

My target is, that files can be hydrated or dehydrated on user request via the Explorer "free up space" or "Always keep on Device" ContextMenu entry. In case I create a new placeholder file that is dehydrated from the beginning, everything works and I can hydrate it via the callback mechanics. But the way around does not work for me. Inside of the Explorer the file will be marked as UnPinned and the file will be marked as syncing, but my application does not receive any callback from `CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DEHYDRATE` or `CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DEHYDRATE_COMPLETION`. Then I wanted to do it manually with `CfDehydratePlaceholder`, but exactly the same behaviour. Nothing happens and the file remains in the state, syncing. Even if I used `CfSetInSyncState` to set the state to `CF_IN_SYNC_STATE_IN_SYNC` it remains to be in the state syncing.
Now I wanted to implement a minimal example with the help of [Cloud Mirror Example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/CloudMirror), but I realized it has the same behaviour. When I try to dehydrate a file again exactly the same happens there as well. From my perspective, it feels for me like cfapi expects an ack from the cloud service, which it never gets.

But in OneDrive everything works like expected. What I am missing? Did I have to set some specific settings?

Comment: CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_XXX are just notifications that something happened (that you should acknowledge when they are not of the COMPLETION-type). If you want to dehydrate you must call CfDehydratePlaceholder. Make sure you check all error returns. CloudMirror only touches the surface.

Comment: I am aware of the things you tell me. But what should i do, when CfDehydratePlaceholder returns without any error. And like i described i already called the function and i already checked the return values in CloudMirror which returning no errors as well. The same in the CloudMirror example. On top i activated that dehydration can be done without the sync engine and still it is not possible.

Comment: A [mcve] is far more accurate in conveying what you have done than paragraphs of prose can be.

Comment: Sorry I had a misunderstanding by myself and I was using the example provided by windows wrong. From my perspective, CloudMirror by Microsoft was already an example, but okay no minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a misunderstanding of the whole API and here is how I understand the API now, to help other people, who are struggling with it.

You have to register your sync root and connecting your app to it. In case of connecting it, you will receive a `CF_CONNECTION_KEY`, which is needed to communicate with the virtual filesystem. Then you can add extended attributes to all files inside of your sync root. The most important are custom attributes you can choose by yourself to identify the file object by your app if needed and then the PinState and SyncState. Mostly the SyncState don't have to be changed by the app, besides marking a file as synced after it was processed by the app. (you can do it at the moment you update your custom attributes) Because in case a file changed, the SyncState will automatically be changed. The PinState declares which final state a file should have. For example UNPINNED means, that the file should be dehydrated, and PINNED the opposite. It does not mean, that the file necessarily has already this state. My misunderstanding was, that I thought in case I unpinned a file, it will be automatically dehydrated. Or in case I pinned a placeholder I will receive a request via the callback function I mentioned in my question. But this is not the case. Your app needs to find out via a FileWatcher (i can recommend my own created FileWatcher project: https://github.com/neXenio/panoptes) that the file attribute of specific files was changed. Then your app has to process every step. Like already mentioned in case of dehydrating, the app needs to call CfDehydratePlaceholder. In case of hydrating, you need to open a transfer session via `CfGetTransferKey` and then hydrate (send the data to the empty file) via the method `CfExecute`, where you need the connection key and the transfer key. And that's are the basics. There is much more to tell about it, but I guess with this beginning, everybody can figure it out by himself.